# Barcode printing for barcode printer page setup in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, barcode, barcode-printing

i have seen many example's on stack overflow but i am not getting what i want. I want to print barcode in barcode printer with 2*0.5 size. i want to setup the crystal report detail section such a way that when the printing starts the barcode printer roll will start printing the multiple barcode

i tried to make the section 3 of crystal report "format with multiple column" and set the width and height of the report but it allows me either to print across and down or down and across but i want the report to be in a single column

i am really tired of searching now so i have posted this question hope i will get the answer and code asap

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try suppressing headers and footers and re-size details section to 2*05, place your bar-code there. Then go to File -> Page Setup and check No Printer and try printing your report again. It should create a new page per detail, so should print a bar-code per label.